# What to do with "drugs" and "medications" tags?

Tags: discussion, tag-management

The tag "medications" has been used 39 times on the site and has the following tag wiki:

> Questions related to intake, use, safety, side effects of medications

The tag "drugs" has been used 27 times and has the following tag wiki (emphasis mine):

> Questions related to **medical drugs** used by doctors for treatment of diseases

The tag has been applied to questions for everything from antibiotics and thyroid medication to marijuana and alcohol.

A few questions use both, but most have only one of them.

This seems confusing to me. I have a few ideas what to do, but there may be more that make sense:

1. Create tag "recreational drugs" and retag the questions that are about alcohol/marijuana with that, then make "drugs" a synonym for "medications"
2. Use" drugs" for questions about both medical and recreational drugs, change tag wiki to reflect that
3. [This site](http://www.differencebetween.net/language/words-language/difference-between-drug-and-medicine/) claims that "drugs" in the medical sense is only used for "stimulants, hallucinogens, and narcotics". I am not a native speaker, so I can't speak to how widespread that is. If so, the tag wiki could be changed to reflect that and questions about medications that aren't in these groups retagged

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up! In the US at least, medication is prescribed or bought over the counter for illness, etc. When taken for non-prescribed purposes (usually recreational or self-medication for depression, etc.), we describe this as "illicit drug use" or "drug abuse". It's not hard and fast; context matters. But a doctor doesn't usually ask "Are you on any drugs?" unless, well... unless they suspect illicit drug use. Otherwise patients might take offense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I totally think the tag "drugs" should be burned, as it is not likely to be used correctly.  I think "recreational drugs" could be a good tag, and I also really want to stab the "s" on the end of "medications" so that it's "medication."  That however might just be too much of a pet peeve.

Comment: Done and done. "Drugs" will be redirected to medication, and "medications" was repaired. There is also a "recreational drugs" tag.

Comment: @anongoodnurse wonderful, thanks!